# React open next page via link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux

I new in React and I looking for any way (the best correct) how to open new page. I html it's like `<a href="/about"></a>` but I read article and that was say don't use it. When I try use `Link` from React I got very more errors.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: You can use [react router](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web)

Comment: what are the errors, when you used `Link`? WIth `<a>` tag, you are just reloading the page, with this you are not getting any advatage.

Comment: Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem. - this error I got

Comment: check this examples https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/tree/dev/examples

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the React realm :) . If you use "a" tag this will make the page to refresh and that is against the concept of SPA. So you need to use a routing library to be able to navigate between pages. Link is a component in the React-Routing library so you need to install it first. Here you can learn more:
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial

Comment: I have question now. If I will use `createBrowserRouter` - can user open page "/about" without opening main page?

Comment: Yes, it's set up to redirect to the correct page.

Comment: I edit my quetion - I add error - how to fix them?

Answer (score 1):

We must first look into the difference between an anchor tag and a Link tag

**Anchor tag**

- Default HTML tag
- Refreshes the page
- Resets useStates

**Link tag**

- Is added with packages
- Doesn't trigger page refresh
- Doesn't reset useStates

From this we conclude that Link tags are preferable to anchor tags, therefore **you should use link tag instead of anchor tag**. In order to have such added, you need to install a package like react-router and set up routing.

**Check these two pages, they contain very elaborate tutorial on how to do routing:**

- [React Router documentation](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/tutorial)
- [Geeks for Geeks tutorial on how to implement routing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-multi-page-website-using-react-js/)

Answer (score 0):

In my react projects, I usually use libraries such as react-router-dom. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom . What's more, it is very useful for you to learn some routing libraries if you want to  improve your react skills.

Comment: I use this library but I got errors.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer stated, you will need a router, because in React, everything lives inside of `index.html`, so we need to navigate without actually leaving the page. `react-router` is a good option, [React Location](https://react-location.tanstack.com/overview) is also a great option, but I would stick to `react-router` if you're just starting out. Another option would be using [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/). It has a built-in file based routing solution, so it should feel more like writing traditional html websites, where every file in your pages directory is a separate page. (And indeed that is what's happening behind the scenes.) Again, this is a bit more advanced and might be out of the question's scope but is definitely worth checking out.